# How to lose focus of UITextField without dismiss keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uitextfield

I want to lose focus of `UITextField` without dismissing the keyboard

I have a `UITextField` and some object which use can long press to show the copy menu. I use `UIMenuController` to show menu and then it's must became `firstResponder => UITextField` will lose edit and dismiss the keyboard.

So, I want to make the keyboard stay on screen but not focus on `UITextField`. It's like Viber when user longpress on message to copy but Viber not dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the next `UITextField` as first responder.

Keyboard will not disappear and the next text field will receive it's 'keystrokes'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for additional functions with UIkeyboard

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[txfield becomeFirstResponder];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];


[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"Keyboard");

 }

 - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"NoKeyboard");

 }
```

Hope this Helps !!!